# Android: Redundancy issue in datahelper class

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables with names disease_table and sysmptoms_table. I retrieved the data from disease_table from the DB and displayed on the listview and when the listitem is clicked, I have to select and display disease category symptoms accordingly and I did that successfully but my code has redundancy, I had to write two methods in the datahelper class to retrieve the symptoms as per the disease in another listview. and I am retrieving the symptom data in list view with the query with the condition of `WHERE "disease_id=1"` with foreign key reference

the code for the methods is as follows,

```
//getting pain symptom names in a arraylist and then display in listview
//this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,symptompain));

public List<String> getAllSymptomPain() {
    List<String> symptompain = null;

    cr = db.query(SYMPTOM_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"symname"}, "diseaseid=1", null, null, null, null);

    if(null != cr){
        symptompain = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                symptompain.add(cr.getString(0));
            }  while (cr.moveToNext());
        }

        if (cr != null && !cr.isClosed()) {
            cr.close();
        }
    }
    return symptompain;
}




//getting colorchange symptom names in a arraylist and then display in listview 
//this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,symptomcolorchange));


public List<String> getAllSymptomColorChange() {
    List<String> symptomcolorchange = null;

    cr = db.query(SYMPTOM_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"symname"}, "diseaseid=2", null, null, null, null);

    if(null != cr){
        symptomcolorchange = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                symptomcolorchange.add(cr.getString(0));
            }  while (cr.moveToNext());
        }

        if (cr != null && !cr.isClosed()) {
            cr.close();
        }
    }
    return symptomcolorchange;
}
```

How can I write these two in a single method and then call it in class which extends listactivity under `onListItemclick` method?

And my `OnListItemClick()` method is as follows :

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String item=(String)getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    if(item.equals("Pain in Teeth")){
        // passing the method here
    }
    else if(item.equals("Pain in Gums")){
        // passing the method here
    }
    else if(item.equals("Pain in Mucosa")){
        // passing the method here
    }
    else if(item.equals("Pain in TMJoint")){
        // passing the method here
    }
    else if(item.equals("Non-Specific Pain")){
        // passing the method here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<String> getSymptomsByDiseaseId(long diseaseId) {

    List<String> symptomsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selection = "diseaseid=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(diseaseId) };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(false, SYMPTOM_TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            symptomsList.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return symptomsList;
}
```